# How to disable locking on the table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions, locking

I need to store data, lifetime of which is supposed to be in most cases something like 1-30 minutes (but still can be 1 day / 1 week). It's just a specific of project - lot of bulk operations performed by many users.

So, typical process of working with this data:

1. User uploads a document, we parse it and pushing data to the table (insertion of 100-70000 rows)
2. We validate data and show errors to the user
3. User corrects data (single correction - update of 1 row)
4. User runs an action after which all uploaded data from document is deleted from the table.

That works nice when only single user works with a system. That works nice when many user uploads documents that produces about 1-5 thousands rows. 
But after insertion of 10 thousands rows SQL server forces table lock and ... that's is a problem.

So, there are different ways to solve this problem, but they all are ugly:

1. Switching to key-value storage - customer doesn't approves using of another storages
2. Can't switch to in-memory solution due to many reasons
3. Group insertion into 2 thousands of rows and specify different transactions for each & handle fails manually - too ugly

And I want next: turn off any locking on specified table. No consistency is needed, only indexes should work.

How I can achieve that? Any other ideas are appreciated too.

Comment: It's really hard to say what the best solution for your table lock issue is without really knowing what's *causing* the lock.  How are you loading data into the table?  Is it the validation/correction that is holding a lock on the table?  If so, you may want to consider using a second, staging, table to load the data into to perform your validation steps before merging it into the live table.

Comment: You cannot turn locking off for `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` in SQL Server - you'll have to change your application to insert fewer than 5000 rows at once, in a single transaction, to avoid table locks. With less than 5000 rows being inserted for a single transaction, row-level locks will be used and your system should perform just fine

Comment: Are you running into slowdowns due to blocking? Why is locking problematic here? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: @Siyual it's just an insertion of many rows. It seems that I can't turn off locking, so I specified hint `rowlock` for insert statement. Sql server eventually decides that using `tablelock` is very good when I'm trying to insert 10-20 thousand rows

Comment: Alos what do you mean "no consistancy is needed" if you don't need any consistancy then why store it in the first place?

Comment: And lock escalation will still happen when you insert 10-20 thousand rows. That is a massive insert that will require a table lock because there is a lot of stuff that has to happen for that much data to be inserted in a single statement. Have you considered using BULK INSERT? Or do your inserts in batches.

Comment: @Zane : yep, there are many users that trying to upload documents. The first user uploads a document that produces 20 thousands of row insertions. Table lock blocks table and so the second user get a long slowdown before the system allows to insert his 10-20 rows.

Comment: @nsinreal is tablelock blocking other queries or something. If so you might be able to change your Isolation level to [Read Commited Snapshot.](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/12/read-committed-snapshot-isolation-writers-block-rcsi/)

Comment: @Zane: "no consistency is needed" means that each user works only with rows produced by his document & each document is processed only by one user. So I'm sure that there is no need in the locks and I can handle manually problems

Comment: @SeanLange I group rows into batch of 200. Then I call my stored procedure that accept list of my custom type. Stored procedure contains single insert statement. But I do all insertions in a single transaction. I don't think that `bulkInsert will help me, because it produces locks too

Comment: @Zane tablelock blocks another insertion. So I can't upload two large documents at the same time

Comment: @Zane So basically I need this kind of isolation: `writers doesn't blocks writers`

Comment: Maybe look into Bulk insert and set lower batch size. There is no Wild West Isolation level.

Comment: @Zane I already set batch size into 200 rows. There is no lock escalation when I try to parallel insert 1 thousand of rows. There is lock escalation only on 10-20 thousands.

Comment: You can't avoid lock escalation when you insert 10-20 thousand rows in a single insert/batch. If you want to avoid table lock escalation with that many rows you are going to have to do this in batches. That means some looping is going to be needed here.

Comment: @SeanLange I have looping (so 10-20 thousand rows - is 50-100 insert statements with 200 rows each). But still in one transaction.

Comment: All this I/O only for validation, then we delete?

Comment: @Biscuits yes, all this I/O is only for providing ability to correct input. Then this data is used to generate another data and gets deleted after that

Comment: Well keeping it all in one transaction means all you have done with looping is slow it down. All rows will be locked until the transaction terminates. This means that lock escalation is going to happen and you will have a table lock. Therefore without some ugly options you either need to commit each batch or deal with locked tables.

Comment: How many concurrent users are you supporting? Is there any possibility of separating the traffic out into what amounts to one table per user? You could create and delete tables as needed or keep a pool of tables and `TRUNCATE` when recycling.

Comment: From [Partitioned Tables and Indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx): "In addition, you can improve performance by enabling lock escalation at the partition level instead of a whole table. This can reduce lock contention on the table." Perhaps it's worth exploring a partition per user. You could create an pool of partitions and assign them to users as needed.

Answer (score 5):

You can disable lock escalation at the table level via ALTER TABLE mytable SET(LOCK_ESCALATION=DISABLE). See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx for details.

Important: lock escalation is a rudimentary resource governance method. Disabling it can result in significantly higher memory consumption which in turn can have all kinds of downstream impact so test thoroughly before turning this loose. This was a major issue with 32-bit platforms that limits VAS of any app to 4GB regardless of how much RAM was installed on the server. Anything above that was usable for data cache only. With 64-bit platforms, SQL Server is able to use whatever memory you have onboard for any purpose.